# jaxb.properties missing at runtime when built with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

I have a project where I want to work with a set of Classes generated by JAXB from an XSD.  With these classes I would like to marshall/unmarshall from XML and JSON.

I've figured out I would need Moxy Eclipselink to do what I need.  I tested my classes and process as an Ant project, then I decided to move it over to Maven for better management.

However, the jaxb.properties file does not seem to be recognized at runtime.

My project has a Maven artifact for the objects, and another artifact for the logic/processing. I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out where to put the jaxb.properties so it could be read.

I have tried

Objects Project

```
/src/main/resources/jaxb.properties
/src/main/java/[namespace]/jaxb.properties
```

Logic Project

```
/src/main/resources/jaxb.properties
/src/main/java/[namespace]/jaxb.properties
```

However, when I try to get the classname of my JAXBContext I still get:

```
class com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl
```

If I modify my run settings by specifying a JVM option of:

```
-Djavax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

I get:

```
class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
```

In both projects I have specified this in the pom.xml

```
<build>
      <resources>
          <resource>
              <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
              <includes>
                  <include>**/*.properties</include>
              </includes>
          </resource>
      </resources>
</build>
```

If I look at the JAR, I see jaxb.properties in there.

[image: Root of JAR]
Now I'm confused.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to make sure the `jaxb.properties` file is under the resources directory in the same package structure as the corresponding model classes.

**Example**

- https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20110322

Comment: Blaise, thanks for that GitHub link. After perusing the structure of the folder, it really started to make sense. I put jaxb.properties in the correct package, and it worked great!

Comment: This was helpful to me, I did a refactoring and moved the model classes in my application but forgot to move the jaxb.properties. The package structure must exactly match under the resources tree. Mine was off by one package and everything broke. This is a very important point.

Comment: Thank you sooo much.  This was my problem too.  This is why I love stackoverflow.  So, many great people like you to help!

Answer (score 1):

Example, in maven the java class

```
 src\main\java\com\example\sitemap\generate\domain
```

and the file jaxb.properties

```
 src\main\resources\com\example\sitemap\generate\domain\jaxb.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it as a System property, if it is cumbersome to add jaxb.properties files for each and every java packages where JAXB pojo classes are present.

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory", "org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory");
```